# Find and replace text with pattern in R

Tags: r

I have a df here below and I need to delete under only the column FRUIT that contains any text with [...].  Please see my df

| DATE | FRUIT | LOCATION | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2010-01-01 | Apple [111-112, 1100, 1151-1152] | USA | 2 |
| 2010-01-01 | Pinapple [22] | USA | 12 |

so ideally I want my df to look like this

| DATE | FRUIT | LOCATION | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2010-01-01 | Apple | USA | 2 |
| 2010-01-01 | Pinapple | USA | 12 |

I tried to use `gsub`, but it is not working out.

```
df$FRUIT<-gsub("[*]", "", df$FRUIT)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can try `gsub` like below

```
df$FRUIT <- gsub("\\s\\[.*\\]","",df$FRUIT)
```

and you will get

```
> df
        DATE    FRUIT LOCATION VALUE
1 2010-01-01    Apple      USA     2
2 2010-01-01 Pinapple      USA    12
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(DATE = c("2010-01-01", "2010-01-01"), FRUIT = c("Apple [111-112, 1100, 1151-1152]",
"Pinapple [22]"), LOCATION = c("USA", "USA"), VALUE = c(2L, 12L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```